# Parse.com: Signup user to role

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

How do you add a user to an existing role when they're signing up? My code below doesn't work, I don't get any errors or any prints in the logs (not sure what I'm doing wrong):

```
Parse.User.signUp(req.body.email, req.body.password, {
    "name": req.body.name,
    "email": req.body.email,
}, {
    success: function(user) {
        var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.Role);
        query.equalTo("name", 'Basic User');

        query.find({
            success: function(roles) {
                alert("HELLO" + roles);

                if (roles.length < 1) {
                    alert("HELLO");

                    console.log("Error Signing Up: No roles for " + signUpRoleGroup + " were found");
                } else {
                    alert("HERE");

                    roles[0].getUsers().add(user);
                    roles[0].save();
                }
            },
            error: function(error) {
                alert("Could not add users to the account " + accountName + " error: " + error.message);
            }
        });
    },
    error: function(user, error) {
        alert("Error signing up user");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what's going on is the caller isn't giving this function a chance to finish saving the role.  The cloud function should wait until the role is saved before invoking response.success() or error().

Here's a promise-returning rewrite of the same code.  Easier on the eyes, I think, and clearer about asynch tasks done serially.  This puts you in more firm control of the response.

```
Parse.Cloud.define("signupAsBasicUser", function(request, response) {
    signupAsBasicUser(request.params.name, request.params.password, request.params.email).then(function(user) {
        response.success(user);
    }, function(error) {
        response.error(error);
    });
});


// return a promise fulfilled with a signed-up user who is added to the 'Basic User" role
//
function signupAsBasicUser(name, password, email) {
    Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
    var user = new Parse.User();
    user.set("username", name);
    user.set("password", password);
    user.set("email", email);
    return user.signUp().then(function() {
        var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.Role);
        query.equalTo("name", 'Basic User');
        return query.find();
    }).then(function(roles) {
        if (roles.length < 1) return Parse.Promise.error("no such role");
        roles[0].getUsers().add(user);
        return roles[0].save();
    }).then(function() {
        return user;
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks - I'm going do some more reading on promises, seems like I don't fully understand why I had to use them in this scenario. (this looked quite useful -http://blog.parse.com/2013/01/29/whats-so-great-about-javascript-promises/)

What puzzles me still is why in my code the cloud code function wasn't waiting for the role to be saved - all I'm doing is saying on the callback of signing up, execute a find query and on that callback save user to role - isn't this still a chain of commands?

Comment: It is, but the last link in that chain is the completion of the save.  The posted code returns before the save has a chance to finish, then calling response.success() terminates the request.  You can skip the promises if you prefer, but don't call response.success until you reach the completion function of the role.save(... success: function() { // ok to respond in here } ).

Comment: Ahhh yes that makes sense - silly mistake treating save as a synchronous function. Thanks!